# Relying on Rails array of integer attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a Job model that has an attribute order_of_assignment which is an array of integers. It stores the order_of_assignment the Accounts have performed, e.g. [1, 2, 3] means Account id 1 assigned the job to Account id 2, Account id 2 assigned the job to Account id 3, and so on. Is it reliable to rely on the update order of this attribute? because I heard that relying on order of DB records/tree is not good. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like the classic anti-pattern of using array/json columns instead of real relational design (join tables). The former is an abomination and the later can be properly ordered any way you want.

Comment: I do agree with @max that using a proper relational table to store this is better here, BUT if you use arrays on the db level then the order is preserved (at least in postgres, should be everywhere that has native arrays). However, if it's not an array but just different records in the database, then without an explicit order clause the order is not guaranteed. If it's a jsonb hash/object, then the order is also not preserved.